# Python Tkinter interface appearance changes depending on OS

Tags: python, tkinter

My application looks beautiful on Windows 
[image]

But on MacOS and Linux it does not look nice at all!
[image]

Is there something I can do to help make this widget appearance consistent across operating systems?

My application source code : http://pae.st/BILs/

Comment: How could we possible tell you what is going on if you don't show us the responsible bit of your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Tkinter's `place` manager for widget layout causes the poor layout of your application on different operating systems.  You should be using either `pack` or `grid` managers, both of which will adjust to the differing widget sizes you encounter.

Comment: @sipiatti: I don't think that's good advice. "more flexible" doesn't necessarily translate to the right choice. Both `grid` and `pack` have strengths and weaknesses. It's better to learn both, then use the right tool for the job.  There are definitely scenarios where I would choose `pack` over `grid`.